# gsap and css transition at the same time possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition, gsap

How can I use a GSAP TweenMax yoyo tween on a dom element that also has the css transition property? 
by default the element performs the tween once (ff, chrome - not ie), but not repeatedly as yoyo? Is there a workaround, except for dropping the css transition?

```
 HTML:
<ol >
        <li class="withcsstransition">with css transition</li>
        <li >without css transition </li>
</ol>

CSS:
.withcsstransition {
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
.active { 
    background: #AAAAAA;
}   

 JS:
 TweenMax.fromTo('li', 0.3, {
    className: "-=active"
 }, {
   className: "+=active",
   yoyo: true,
   repeat: -1,
 });
```

[codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqPZeG)

Comment: Not really sure what the intended behaviour is. Can you elaborate more on that please?

Comment: @TahirAhmed The element with the css transition style should also be subject to the yoyo tween. please have a look at the codepen example where one items has a bg color tween while the other has not. the only difference is the css transform rule. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `all` in your `transition` CSS property to specifically target a property i.e. `min-height`. So the `transition` line of your CSS should look like:

```
...
transition: min-height 0.8s ease;
...
```

I don't fully understand the *why* behind it. It seems to me that somehow the `transition` property's `all` keyword overrides and takes precedence over any CSS property that gets later applied to any element.

Comment: Thanks Tahir for your suggestion which lead me to further investigation.  I know think that the tweenmax tween takes place on all list elements but uses the timing of the css rule instead of the timing of its own tween (which is wired). I found that out by delaying the repeat of the tweenmax tween to give the css rule enough time to finish. I edited the [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqPZeG) so one can see both tweens next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just spend half a day with the same problem. My GSAP animations all got really laggy and the easing didn't seem to work. I was using some css transitions with the property all to change the color of the header and to animate the burger menu. As I finally removed the all property and replaced it with backgound-color and transform, everything worked fine.